# Custom object mapper bean changing the default properties of open Feign Client / auto configured objectMapper bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have spring's open feign client configurations like the following:

```
public class AppFeignConfiguration
{
@Bean
public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder()
{
    return new FeignErrorDecoder();
}


@Bean
public Logger.Level logger()
{
    return Logger.Level.FULL;
}


@Bean
public Request.Options options()
{
    return new Request.Options( 30000, 30000 );
}
}
```

and I provide it as a configuration in the `@FeignClient` as the following

```
@FeignClient ( value = "apigateway-service", configuration = AppFeignConfiguration.class)
```

I believe FeignClient has its default configuration for deserializing the response (maybe an  ObjectMapper with some properties).

All good so far. Everything was working as expected.

Then I created a custom object mapper and returned it as a bean like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig
{
  @Bean ( name = "plainObjectMapper")
  public ObjectMapper plainObjectMapper()
  {
      return new ObjectMapper();
  }
}
```

The problem now is, this is messing with the default deserializing configurations of `FeignClient`.

Meaning, without the custom `plainObjectMapper`, it used to work fine without any json parsing errors. But after creating the custom `plainObjectMapper` as a bean, `FeignClient` is throwing exceptions saying some unknown properties or something.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "xyz" (class abc.def.ghi.class), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException
```

I confirmed this by removing the custom `plainObjectMapper` and it worked fine just as it used to before.

This seems to be strange! I have given the bean a custom name which should not mess with the bean created by springboot.

How can I overcome this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not completely correct.

If you look at `FeignClientsConfiguration` [source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/FeignClientsConfiguration.java#L56), you can see that its encoders rely on `HttpMessageConverters` class.

Then, `HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration` ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java#L62)) itself depends on `JacksonAutoConfiguration`.

The latter creates the default `ObjectMapper` bean only if there is no manually created object mapper in context (see `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` [on the corresponding method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1c70b6735a9f57b11393277a0442478445b6d2ac/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L99)) - the different bean name doesn't matter in this case.

So, it happens that Feign is implicitly relying on this auto-configured `ObjectMapper` but only until you create your own. Then it starts to use yours. Same with many other spring beans.

If you really need to have your own `ObjectMapper` bean, then you need to configure it properly. But you can customize the auto-configured one instead via configuration properties - see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

Comment: but @amseager, springboot creates a bean of ObjectMapper by itself.  How come this doesn't contaminate the FeignClient's ObjectMapper?

Comment: After  a little research, I see that `ObjectMapper` is created by one or the other autoconfig if its not present. and if I create a brean of the same, all the dependencies which needed object mapper is going to use the one which I have created. And there is just one ObjectMapper bean in the whole application. Does this not cause issue when we need multiple beans with different properties?

Comment: Yes, there is only one `ObjectMapper` autoconfigured bean in the regular spring boot app used by many other libs including `spring-cloud-openfeign`. And it's not created when you're doing it manually because of `@ConditionalOn...` annotations. That's where the spring boot's magic ends. So, as the easiest solution, I wouldn't recommend you to create your own `ObjectMapper` bean (or multiple beans) as long as it's possible but to customize the default one instead.

Comment: I Got it. But isn't this a flaw? I mean customized bean for some other purpose is contaminating the properties of some other `autoconfigured bean`. Now if I want to continue with autoconfiguraiton and customized bean, I have to copy all the properties from autoconfiguration.

Comment: I think it's one of the weaknesses of the spring boot itself when you need to step away from its main idea about auto-configurations.

Comment: Customizing the default `ObjectMapper` is not a solution at all, as that will still affect everything else that is using this bean.  This is Spring stupidity, `ObjectMapper`s should not be shared like this.  When your application uses REST, Feign, RabbitMQ, etc, and also has some need for a custom `ObjectMapper` it is practically impossible to just customize the default one to suit all those different needs.